# R services in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, r, sql-server-2016, rsqlserver

Recently, a tech support specialist installed SQL Server 2016 Management Studio in my computer. When I asked about the possibility of using integrated R services in SSMS, he said I need to have stand alone SQL server installed in order to use that feature (which is not going to happen as individual license is pretty expensive). 
Can somebody shed some light on using R services from SQL server 2016? Do I really need stand alone SQL server? or there is a workaround? 
Thank you

poshan

Comment: Did you read the documentation by Microsoft about this topic?

Comment: No, I have not. If you know the link for the documentation that addresses this topic that would be very helpful for me and others. Thank you

Comment: I'm sure you can google it and find it.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2016 Management Studio is a client tool that connects to the Microsoft SQL Server 2016. If R-service already installed (as part of setup wizard, if you have chosen Database Engine Services and R-Services (In-Database)), you can connect to the SQL Server and execute R-script from Management Studio setup in your machine.

Some useful documentation:-
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt696069.aspx